# First \addbibresource ignored

Tags: biblatex, biber

In the following test document using `\WithRSfalse` I get two entries in the bibliography, but after switch to `\WithRStrue` only the entry from the second bib file appear.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newif\ifWithRS
\WithRSfalse

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-1.bib}
@book{foo,
  author       = {XXX, YYY},
  title        = {FOO},
  date         = 1901,
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-2.bib}
@book{bar,
  author       = {UUU, VVV},
  title        = {BAR},
  date         = 1902,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\ifWithRS
  \addbibresource[label=rs1]{\jobname-1.bib}
  \addbibresource[label=rs1]{\jobname-2.bib}
\else
  \addbibresource{\jobname-1.bib}
  \addbibresource{\jobname-2.bib}
\fi

\begin{document}
BlaBla
\ifWithRS
  \refsection[rs1]%
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
  \endrefsection
\else
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\fi
\end{document}
```

I compiled with:

```
pdflatex xxx ; biber xxx ; pdflatex xxx ; pdflatex xxx
```

Is this a bug or my misunderstanding?

Comment: Hence both `\addbibresource` have the same label I expect that both are respected. Without any label all  `\addbibresource` commands are effective.

Answer (score 3):

The `label` argument to `\addbibresource` needs to be a *unique* identifier for the `.bib` file. So you can't use `label=rs1` for two different sources, the later overwrites the earlier mention.

I have clarified the documentation to be more explicit about this https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/b2d6b2466a013ce4dabf94d44e58b2c27fb1fd17.

The optional argument of `refsection` and `\newrefsection` accepts a list of resource labels, so you could use different labels and give both when you start the new refsection.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newif\ifWithRS
\WithRStrue

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-1.bib}
@book{foo,
  author       = {XXX, YYY},
  title        = {FOO},
  date         = 1901,
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-2.bib}
@book{bar,
  author       = {UUU, VVV},
  title        = {BAR},
  date         = 1902,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\ifWithRS
  \addbibresource[label=rs1]{\jobname-1.bib}
  \addbibresource[label=rs2]{\jobname-2.bib}
\else
  \addbibresource{\jobname-1.bib}
  \addbibresource{\jobname-2.bib}
\fi

\begin{document}
BlaBla
\ifWithRS
  \newrefsection[rs1,rs2]
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
  \endrefsection
\else
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\fi
\end{document}
```

Strictly speaking `\refsection` is not meant for direct use. You can either use `\newrefsection`

```
  \newrefsection[rs1,rs2]
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
  \endrefsection
```

or the environment version

```
  \begin{refsection}[rs1,rs2]
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
  \end{refsection}
```

Due to the way LaTeX implements environments `\refsection[rs1,rs2]` also works, but it is not recommended.

---

Just in case it was not clear from the beginning, a `refsection` does not *need* the optional argument giving resource labels. If no label is given, all defined resources are assumed. In the MWE the same result could be obtained by omitting the `[rs1,rs2]`

```
  \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
  \end{refsection}
```

The optional argument is only needed if you want to restrict a certain refsection to use only certain data sources and not all defines resources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will think about.